# C# check if time is now send cached items

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, caching

I am currently Caching a list of items and i want to be able to send everything that is cached out to another method when the time is 4pm Easter time or 8 UTC.

```
_cacheOptions.SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
//serialize Cache
await _cache.SetStringAsync(_cacheKey, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserializedChanges), _cacheOptions);
```

The current task that I am stuck on is to write an if statement that would check if the time is 4pm eastern or not. this process would repeat daily so only checking time not date

example

```
var timeNow = (DateTime.UtcNow)
if( timeNow == 4pm)
{
run method
}
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like caching is the right tool for this job. Setting the expiration for a cached item is only used when you read or write the cached entry, not for triggering an event. You probably want to look at some scheduling service (cron, Windows Scheduler, etc).

Comment: Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0 About half way down the page is an example of a PostEvictionCallback. It would like do what you want but I agree is gunr2171 that using a cache like that is not a good idea. Mainly because if your app server runs low on memory or goes to sleep it will dump the cache. You can even trust information to be in the cache. Sounds more like you need a console or function app with a cron job.

Comment: I am currently caching changes on the server i only posted a small snippet of the code for you guys to understand what i need it for. i am trying to write an if statement that would compare a time i declare which will be 4pm eastern time and in the if i want to say if it is 4pm do this if not then ignore.

Comment: The problem is that when you add something to a cache, there is no guarantee that the cached item will be in the cache when you go looking for it; the cache is allowed to delete cached items at any time. Use another data structure (say a `Dictionary<string, object>` to store the items and come up with a mechanism that will raise an event at 4pm

Answer (score -1):

If the time is 8 utc then refresh cache

```
var time = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
if (time.Hour.Equals(8))
 {
    await _cache.RefreshAsync(_cacheKey);
 }
```